# Lua - variables namespace inside module

Tags: inheritance, lua

I've created a module called `BaseModule` with variable `template_path` and function `get_template` using this variable:

```
module("BaseModule", package.seeall)
template_path = '/BASEMODULE_PATH/file.tmpl'
function get_template()
  print template_path
end
```

Then I create another module called "ChildModule"

```
local BaseModule = require "BaseModule"
module("ChildModule", package.seeall)
setmetatable(ChildModule, {__index = BaseModule})
template_path = '/CHILDMODULE_PATH/file.tmpl'
some_child_specific_variable = 1
```

By doing `setmetatable` I want to copy all variables and functions from `BaseModule` to `ChildModule` (let's say *inherit them*) and add some extra methods and variables to a new module.

The problem is when I call

```
ChildModule.get_template
```

I expect it to return **`/CHILDMODULE_PATH/file.tmpl`** but doesn't. It returns **`/BASEMODULE_PATH/file.tmpl`**.

However when I access `ChildModule.template_path` it contains the correct value (from `ChildModule`).

What can I do to make Lua use `ChildModule` variables in `ChildModule.get_template` method but not to use `BaseModule` (parent module) variables? There's no **this** object in Lua so how can I tell Lua to use a current value?

Comment: The `get_template` function don't compile. I suppose you forgot the parentheses during the posting?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're still using the deprecated version of Lua. Anyways, you need to set the `template_path` value inside the `BaseModule` using some function, and set the `template_path` in the base to be `local`. So, something like this:

### BaseModule

```
module("BaseModule", package.seeall)
local template_path = "/BASEMODULE_PATH/file.tmpl"
function get_template()
  print(template_path)
end
function set_template( sLine )
  template_path = sLine
end
```

### ChildModule

```
local BaseModule = require "BaseModule"
module("ChildModule", package.seeall)
setmetatable(ChildModule, {__index = BaseModule})
ChildModule.set_template( "/CHILDMODULE_PATH/file.tmpl" )
some_child_specific_variable = 1
ChildModule.get_template()
```

Since you're inheriting, you *must not* try to set global variables of base-module directly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to manipulate variables whereas you probably want to manipulate properties of the objects you are creating. Maybe something like this:

```
-- base.lua
local M = {}
M.template_path = '/BASEMODULE_PATH/file.tmpl'
function M:get_template()
  return self.template_path
end
return M

-- child.lua
local M = {}
setmetatable(M, {__index = require "base"})
M.template_path = '/CHILDMODULE_PATH/file.tmpl'
M.some_child_specific_variable = 1
return M

-- main.lua
local base = require "base"
local child = require "child"

print(base:get_template(), child:get_template(),
  child.some_child_specific_variable)
```

This will print:

```
/BASEMODULE_PATH/file.tmpl  /CHILDMODULE_PATH/file.tmpl 1
```

as you would expect.

BTW, you can turn `child.lua` into a one-liner:

```
return setmetatable({template_path = '/CHILDMODULE_PATH/file.tmpl',
  some_child_specific_variable = 1}, {__index = require "base"})
```

Not that you should, but you could.